# Deleting all False values from dataframe/series

Tags: python, database, pandas

I have a series with only 2 columns. (ex: (Alabama, Alabama) False )

```
                  0
Alabama Alabama False
Alabama Alaska  False
Alabama Arizona False
Alabama Arkansas    True
Alabama California  True
Alabama Colorado    True
```

I want to remove all the False values from the series. I tried:

```
p = test2[test2['Alabama','Alabama'] == True]
```

which works for dataframes but doesnt seem to work for series.

Answer (score 5):

You can just do:

```
p = test2[test2==True]
```

or

```
p = test2[test2]
```

With Series, you don't need to specify columns.